# JDBC and utf8mb4 encoding the emoji symbol 

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, emoji, utf8mb4

I use Mysql 5.7.18 and I faced an issue with emoji symbols when updating from `JDBC`.

Table creation: `body` is typed `utf8` and `localizations` is `utf8mb4`

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `body` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `localizations` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Now I use `SequelPro` to insert data. To do it correctly I press `Database -> View using encoding -> utf8mb4`. Insertion code:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(body, localizations) VALUES ('test', '');
```

Then I try to load it from jdbc. Here is connection string part currently used in project (formatting is used here only for convenient reading):

```
?useEncoding=true
&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

It successfully loads `localizations` from database. But updating table from JDBC returns error:

```
SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x94\xA5"}...' for column 'localizations'
```

I suppose that's because of connection encoding. `SequelPro` has a `Show server variables` option and here is the diff between `utf8` and `utf8mb4`:

```
character_set_client = utf8mb4
character_set_connection = utf8mb4
character_set_results = utf8mb4
collation_connection = utf8mb4_general_ci
```

So I try to modify connection string:

```
?useEncoding=true
&characterEncoding=UTF-8
&sessionVariables=
  character_set_client=utf8mb4,
  character_set_connection=utf8mb4,
  character_set_results=utf8mb4,
  collation_connection=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Still the same issue. Any advice please?

Comment: Ha, I thought you were trying to fiddle with your post title, but you actually mean encoding the character . *I hate emoji...*

Comment: This is first time I used non-symbolic emoji, 8-bit character was always enough for me. But end users enjoy emoji so gotta support it =)

Comment: Try executing `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'` immediately after establishing your Connection.

Comment: I found no way to set encoding on mysql 5. Gord's suggestion seems to be a workaround, but it works. Decided to use it. Would you post your solution as a separate answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using old version of mysql-connector-java, consider to upgrade to newer version. Upgrade version of mysql-connector-java from 5.1.31 to 5.1.49 solved my issue.
My JDBC_URL is **"jdbc:mysql://{HOST}:{PORT}/{DBNAME}?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8";**

Answer (score 1):

The error message says (I think) that JDBC was not told `utf8mb4`...

I suspect `useEncoding` was a typo:

```
?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8  -- in the getConnection() call.
```

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#best_practice

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. I found out in my session variables that

`character_set_client=utf8mb4`

but

`character_set_server=utf8`

As suggested in links below,

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-server.html

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

I removed characterEncoding, charSet and useEncoding properties from JDBC config and restarted mysql server with

`--character-set-server=utf8mb4`

Worked like a Charm!